# curl php alwaysing getting error 403

Tags: php, curl

hello im trying to get a page using curl but always getting error 403. Is there any way to get this web page?

My source code is like this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);
$LOGINURL = "https://sso.orange.fr/espace-client/desimlockage";
$ch = curl_init();
$headers[] = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Host:iz.orange.fr";
$headers[] = "Referer:http://www.sosh.fr/espace-client-accueil";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: curl/7.39.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: maybe your ip is banned, i get `< HTTP/1.1 302 Found`  followed by `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
`

Comment: maybe changing the user-agent: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Answer (score 0):

comment curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); and try once. hope it'll help.